# Can a non US resident (international billing address) rent a car using Priceline bidding?

Tags: car-rentals, opaque-provider

I checked online and on Priceline bidding a rental car rate is significantly cheaper than outside of the US (over 20%), including the CDW insurance. 
But, this rate is only available for credit cards with billing address within the US. Which is not the case by me. 
Could I pay with one card and then show up to the rental with another card? 
(I have access to a card with a US billing address)

Any other way to get access to those rates?

Comment: in which country you intend to rent a car?

Comment: In the USA, NY, JFK to be exact

Comment: I cannot use that card to bring with me, I can only rent with it (it doesn't belong to me)

Comment: Note that some banks don't verify the billing address field when making an online purchase, so you might as well get away with inserting a US-based address for your own card.

Answer (score 2):

> NO,a non US resident (international billing address) cannot rent a car
>   using Priceline bidding, the only option is available to choose a
>   reservation where  payment is not required until you pick up the
>   vehicle.

Answer is from official priceline website :

https://www.priceline.com/home/
[image]

[image]